# Why is container BaseOS/ CoreOS a thing?

Tags: docker, containers, virtualization, coreos

I thought the whole point of containerization was to abstract the GuestOS to make the application more agnostic of where it runs aka more "serverless," and to make spinning up containers a more lightweight process. You just package up your app with what it needs and deploy them as needed for horizontal scale and you don't have to worry about hypervisors. The diagram below has been my go-to for explaining the concept of a container. [image: containerization]

But now I came across the concept of BaseOS as I keep seeing the name CoreOS pop up. This seems to be counter intuitive to the theme of abstraction. Due to the fact that the BaseOS and the HostOS can "share a kernel," does it somehow keep the process lightweight without a traditional hypervisor needed to interact with hardware resources? How is the additional OS of benefit?
[image]

Comment: A few good points are mentioned here [What is a container?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EnJ7qX9fkcU), by VMware Cloud-Native, that might shed some light.